# Codeigniter 4 Mostrar datos en el index

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

Que tal ando trabajando en mi primera aplicacion con codeigniter 4, todo bien por el momento con el logi, las tablas y el MVC, pero se me presenta un problema al momento de mostrar datos en le index, en resumen ando realizando una aplicacion para una tienda con inventario todo bien cuando hice el inventario sube, actualiza y elimina tambien dentro del usuario admin muestra la tabla pero cuando quiero mostrar los datos en una tabla en el index antes del login no me permite Subo codigo:

Aca el index

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>Listado Mac</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="table table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Ubicacion</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Garantia</th>
            <th>Precio de Etiqueta</th>

          </tr>
        <?php foreach($datos as $key): ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->id_inv ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->tipo ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->ubicacion ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->marca ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->estado ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->modelo ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->color ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->stock ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->garantia ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $key->precio_etiqueta ?></td>
        
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Aca el controlador que cree aparte porque en el Home no me dejaba pense q creando uno aparte pero tampoco

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

   use App\Models\IndexModel;

    class Index extends BaseController
   {

public function index()
{

    $Crud = new IndexModel();
    $datos = $Crud->listarNombresmac();

    $data =[ 

            "datos" => $datos,
            ];
    
    return view('index');
}

}
```

Y aca el modelo igual cree un independiente:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

  use CodeIgniter\Model;

  class IndexModel extends Model {
     public function ListarNombresmac() {
     $Nombres = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM inventario");
     return $Nombres->getResult();
   }

}
```

Aca las rutas:

```
$routes->get('/', 'Index::index');
$routes->get('/computadoras', 'Home::computadoras');
$routes->get('/login', 'Home::ingresar');
$routes->get('/inicio', 'Home::inicio');
$routes->post('/login', 'Home::login');
$routes->get('/salir', 'Home::salir');
```

Cuando estoy dentro del login todo funciona bien puedo crear tablas pero una ves quiero mostrar tablas en el index para informacion me sale error : Undefined variable $datos.

Revise las rutas verifique todo pero sin poder encontrar la razon por la cual me sale ese error, si alguien algunas ves tuvo ese problema agradeceria mucho un poco de ayuda, gracias.

Comment: No sería más bien `$this->load->view('index', $data);` en lugar de `return view('index');`?

Comment: Gracias tambien intente con $this->load->view('index', $data); sin resultados.

Comment: debuguea, verifica que  `$Crud->listarNombresmac();`en el controlador devuelva algún dato.

Comment: pues quizás con `return view('index', $data);`

Comment: al view tenes q pasarle la data https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#view